Как поучаствовать в недельном рейтинге
Можете мне помочь, как получить представителя в недельном рейтинге, у меня репутация только за сегодня 120 и за всю неделю, а топ 1 недельного рейтинга 60. Но меня не показывают в топе, я не знаю почему, но мои догадки из-за того, что у меня нет представителя. Как мне получить этого представителя?
Может есть другая проблема из-за которой я не могу поучаствовать в недельном рейтинге. Пожалуйста, помогите мне справится с этой проблемой, чтобы я смог поучаствовать в недельном рейтинге.

Дело скорее всего в том, что рейтинг ещё не успел обновиться.

@wchistow, дело в том, что его в списке нельзя найти https://i.sstatic.net/nSkSIXTP.png, я подумала, может это потому что нет определнного срока на сайте и нашла в ленте более старого пользователя(https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/268379/anatolii?tab=topactivity), но тоже не отображается https://i.sstatic.net/M6OhJaBp.png, но можно заметить, что есть такой же участник, который недавно зарегестрировался, и он в списке https://i.sstatic.net/bZDieTPU.png //мне не совсем понятно по какому принципу это генерируется, по себе помню, как один день просто стало отображаться...может я что то нажала)))

я так же искала по старому нику...но в списке просто не находит

@Dev18, буду признателен, если вспомните и скажите что нажали.

модераторы придут скажут. Я на тот момент добавляла сообщества...(играет ли это роль?)я посмотрела, вроде у вас такие же...так что это не то...я так не помню, чтоб что то задуманно делала...разве что случайно, а значит не вспомню. Но точно помню, как вдруг стал светиться "рейтинг"...рубеж кармы 500? надо найти участника с 500 проверить...===>https://i.sstatic.net/LhKVwI6d.png вот 2 месяца на сайте +500 а вот 200 репутация https://i.sstatic.net/ljjHYX9F.png

@Dev18, это не из-за 500 репутации. На втором месте стоит участник с 301 репутацией.

но мои догадки из-за того, что у меня нет представителя =>а в какой справке вы прочли про это? и что такое представитель  в данном контексте

Там написано, что у меня нет представителя. У тех кто участвует в рейтинге вместо нет представителя пишут изменять(допустим +1 или -1). Также иногда там пишут не ранжировался.

ужасный перевод, это от гугл, да ранжировался...)))ну да, https://i.sstatic.net/itLAuIaj.png //очень интересный вопрос. подписалась, чтоб ответ узнать.

Добавь ссылку, где ты смотришь и скриншот, где ты не отображаешься

Ну вот же все отображается: https://i.sstatic.net/XWRvD3fc.png Смотрю здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=week. Скорее всего на момент вопроса просто рейтинг не успел обновиться.

@insolor, а почему у него в профиле нету ашТаг ранг такой то https://i.sstatic.net/pBe5UAcf.png

@Dev18 потому что участник в течение 41 дня?

@insolor, не, выше примеры, что есть 16 дней участник в ранге и есть пример 6 лет не в ранге

я логику не поняла этого алгоритма.

@Dev18, ну это уже отдельный вопрос.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315958/cannot-find-myself-in-stack-overflow-rating/315959#315959 вот в чате ссылку отправили, но мне лично мало, что отвечает. Почему некоторые пользователи не в ранге другие в,....я вроде и балы сравнивала и длительность на сайте

Матвей, когда обновится кеш, вы будете в рейтинге(24часа?не точно) . В чате модератор говорит, что начальный порог 200. У вас 318-120(заработаные сегодня) делает меньше 200. Так что ответ это минимальный порог. Но нигде не написано к сожалению об этом.

...правда я только недавно заметила у себя этот аштаг....а не тогда. когда 200 было...наверно просто я не обращаю внимание на все это

Я не знаю, как, но меня научила показывать в топе

@Matvj см. первый комментарий. Топ обновляется не сразу, а с некоторой задержкой.

@insolor, я уже понял
